# Group action such that $H^1(G, L^{\times}) \neq \{1\}$.

Tags: field-theory, group-actions, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

I am looking for an example of a field $L$ together with a group morphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut_{field}}(L)$ (i.e. a group $G$ acts by field automorphisms on $L$), and such that the cohomology group $H^1(G, L^{\times})$ is not trivial.

The typical example of such action is when $L$ is a Galois extension of some subfield $K$, and $G$ denotes the Galois group, but in that case Hilbert 90 asserts the vanishing of the first cohomology group.

(The motivation behind this question is an exercise in chap. I of Silverman's book "Arithmetic of elliptic curves", which states that $\mathbb P^n(L^G) = \mathbb P^n(L)^G$, where $L/K$ is Galois and $G$ the Galois group — this uses Hilbert 90 !).

Comment: $L^G$ is always a subfield. What would be the actions of $G=L$ or $G=L^\times$?

Comment: @CaptainLama : yes, sorry, I removed my unnecessary assumption and comment.

Comment: I'm not sure there are counterexamples. The thing is that $L/L^G$ is Galois, and while $G$ is not always the Galois group (when it is infinite, there are topological considerations), it must be dense in it, so it does not seem unlikely that Hilbert 90 still applies. I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using Hilbert 90 on that exercise--if I'm not being dumb, it holds trivially for any action of $G$ on $L$.  Indeed, if $[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]\in\mathbb{P}^n(L)^G$ with (say) $x_0\neq 0$, then $[1,x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0]$ has coordinates in $L^G$.

Comment: @EricWofsey : you seem to be right, so the hint in Silverman's book is a bit strange. On the other, Hilbert 90 shows that there is a "universal" element $a \in L$ (not depending on $x$) such that for every $[x_0:...:x_n] \in \mathbb P^n(L)^G$, the coordinates $a x_i \in L^G$ (for every $i$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to get such examples is to consider trivial actions.  For instance, let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $G$ act on any field $L$ trivially.  Then $H^1(G,L^\times)\cong L^\times$.  More generally, with $G=\mathbb{Z}$ acting possibly nontrivially on $L$, then $H^1(G,L^\times)$ is isomorphic to the coinvariants $L^\times_G$.  (To verify these calculations you can use the very simple free resolution of the trivial module $\mathbb{Z}$ over the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]\cong\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$: $0\to \mathbb{Z}[G]\stackrel{t-1}\to\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}\to 0.$)

Answer (score 1):

In Eric Wofsey's answer, with $\Bbb{Z}$ acting trivially on $L^\times$,

The map is $a\in L^\times \to f_a\in H^1(\Bbb{Z},L^\times), f_a(\{n,m\})= a^{n-m}$ which is a cocycle because it satisfies $f_a(\{n,m\})=m.f_a(\{n-m,0\})$ and $f_a(\{n,m\}) f_a(\{m,l\})=f_a(\{n,l\})$.

We quotient those by the coboundaries, ie. the cocycles of the form $f(\{n,m\})= (n.b)/(m.b)=b/b=1$.